# How can I extract TCP SYN flag from pcap file and detect SYN Flood attack using Python (Scapy)?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tcp

I'm parsing a PCAP file and I need to extract only TCP flags (SYN) for detect a SYN Flood attack.
I use Python and scapy.

The main goal is a way of detecting a SYN flood attack!
I need to count a number of TCP flags (SYN) for each IP address and print a list with :
{IP: number of SYN flag} sorted by number of SYN flag.
Could somebody help me?

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from scapy.all import *
pkts = PcapReader("test.pcap")
dict_ips = dict()
```

Comment: Thanks. How can I print a list with : {IP: number of SYN flag} sorted by number of SYN flag?

Comment: You can put the ip address in a dictionary as the key and the count as value,  then sort it

Comment: I tried hard, but is not working:  https://bpaste.net/show/0094b136f276

Comment: Thanks @BhargavRao for re-opening this question!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best object for what you are trying to do is a `Counter` (from `collections`).

The "not-so-Pythonic" (but easier to read if you're not used to Python) way of writing this would be:

```
from scapy.all import PcapReader, TCP
from collections import Counter
count = Counter()
for pkt in PcapReader("test.pcap"):
    if TCP in pkt and pkt[TCP].flags & 2:  # TCP SYN packet
        src = pkt.sprintf('{IP:%IP.src%}{IPv6:%IPv6.src%}')
        count[src] += 1
```

It's easy to write this as a comprehension:

```
from scapy.all import PcapReader, TCP
from collections import Counter
count = Counter(
    pkt.sprintf('{IP:%IP.src%}{IPv6:%IPv6.src%}')
    for pkt in PcapReader('test.pcap')
    if TCP in pkt and pkt[TCP].flags & 2
)
```

Then, a `Counter` behaves like a `dict` object:

```
>>> count["1.2.3.4"]
12
```

But a `Counter` has a handy `.most_common()` method:

```
>>> count.most_common(1)
[('1.2.3.4', 12)]
>>> count.most_common()
[('1.2.3.4', 12), [...]]
```

As a conclusion I have to mention that Scapy has poor performances when it comes to parsing a lot of packets (and if we are talking about flood, that might be the case). If I were you, I would still use a `Counter`, but I would generate the sources by using a `subprocess.Popen()` call to `tcpdump` or `tshark` instead of Scapy's `PcapReader`.

Comment: Thanks for helping!